# How to setup IPTables to allow TCP port 599?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, amazon-web-services

I'm new to IPTables and I believe I'm overlooking something obvious.

This is my settings:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 12 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:isakmp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipsec-nat-t
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  ip-10-10-10-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal/24  anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             ip-10-10-10-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal/24  policy match dir out pol ipsec proto esp
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Then I tried to open port 599:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 599 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 599 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Unfortunately, my existing IPTables still blocks it and I don't understand why.
AWS health check still can't do a TCP ping on 599 port.  Any clue what I'm missing?

**Latest UPDATE:**

```
sudo iptables -vnL --line-numbers



 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    11582  695K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:599 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
2     309K   19M DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 12 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
3     6546  386K            all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
4    11329 7186K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
5       24  1440 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:599 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
6      246 13224 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
8       50  2227 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
9        2   400 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:500
10       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:4500
11    6275  371K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.10.10.0/24        0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir in pol ipsec proto 50
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.10.10.0/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec proto 50
3        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 18608 packets, 2153K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, iptables -A INPUT appends a rule to the end.  Your current last rule is:

`DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere`

So, it gets added to the end, after the drop rule, and never gets reached.  You will want to list rules with line numbers:

`iptables -nL --line-numbers`

Then use `iptables -I INPUT 5 ...` (or whatever line number) to add at a specific position.

If all traffic for port 599 should be allowed back out (with NEW,ESTABLISHED), so you shouldn't need the OUTPUT rule.

If this is running on an ec2 instance, you'll want to make sure security groups allow 599 in also.  Although with aws security groups, iptables on the individual instances may not quite be necessary...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have followed your advice and added the rule twice, once just before the `Drop` and again as the first rule.  Unfortunately, it is still blocked. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Try to run tcpdump on the interface and see if you are seeing any packets for port 599 at all.  If not, perhaps the packets aren't even reaching your instance.

Comment: I also like to use -v as an option.  It enables verbose mode, which will tell how many packets matched that rule: ```12  720  DROP  all  --  *  *  218.145.31.179  0.0.0.0/0```... that is, first two fields are packets and bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this `sudo tcpdump -v | grep 599` but it doesn't find anything: `tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`. This is really strange.  It must have something to do with iptables settings...

Comment: I would do: ```tcpdump -i eth0 port 599```, but what you did probably works too.  Again, if this is an ec2 instance on aws, I would check the security groups to make sure 599 is allowed to the instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated the question with a screenshot of the security group. Everything is open.  I get actually now some traffic after all on that port, which I have added to the question. However, the health check still fails to connect. Very strange....

Comment: Can you post results of iptables command with -v, so we can see if packets are matching, and which rules?

Comment: Certainly. I have added it to the question. I have cleaned up some of my previous attempts to keep the content management. Thank you

Comment: My mistake was that no app was listening to my port. Hence AWS health check failed.  Hence opening just a port isn't enough. Some service needs to reply back to make TCP health check work. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed that you had something listening for it to check, that it was failing to reach.